# Wi-Fi connection problems with Ubuntu 17.04 and RT3290 wireless card

Tags: drivers, internet, connection, ralink

I have recently installed Ubuntu 17.04 in a dual-boot with Windows 8 (in case it matters).

I have a problem with wireless connection. It works in general, but when I download large files the connection tends to drop suddenly from time to time, so that I have to reestablish it.

Apparently, there is a problem with the wireless card (Ralink RT3290 in my laptop), however, the connection is stable on Windows. Perhaps, something wrong with the drivers?

After some googling, I found out that people with the very same wireless card often encounter somewhat similar problems. For instance, they have even connecting to Wi-Fi, though this is not the case for me.

I tried to reinstall drivers following [this link](http://onthim.blogspot.ru/2015/06/install-ralink-rt3290-wi-fi-driver-on.html), but it did not work well for me, in a sense that the connection still gets lost when I download large files.

I wonder if someone faced this problem and/or knows the solution to it.

Some useful outputs:

> lspci | grep -i network

yields

> Network controller: Ralink corp. RT3290 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe

As for the drivers, I used

> sudo lshw -C network

and obtained

```
*-network                 
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
   vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
   physical id: 0.1
   bus info: pci@0000:02:00.1
   logical name: enp2s0f1
   version: 12
   serial: 10:c3:7b:8c:9e:9b
   size: 10Mbit/s
   capacity: 1Gbit/s
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl8411-2_0.0.1 07/08/13 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
   resources: irq:47 ioport:e000(size=256) memory:f7914000-f7914fff memory:f7910000-f7913fff
*-network
   description: Wireless interface
   product: RT3290 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe
   vendor: Ralink corp.
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
   logical name: wlp3s0f0
   version: 00
   serial: 54:35:30:a2:55:bd
   width: 32 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rt2800pci driverversion=4.10.0-33-generic firmware=0.37 ip=192.168.0.81 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
   resources: irq:19 memory:f7810000-f781ffff
```

I am a little bit of a newbie for Linux. Hence, in case any other outputs are needed, please, do not hesitate to tell me.